# OS X 10.7 add multiple windows workgroups

Tags: macos, windows, network, smb

I have multiple Windows Workgroups on my network, Does 10.7 have the ability to add more than one Workgroup at a time?

I open up System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> WINS (Tab) -> Workgroup

I select/toggle between the Workgroups I need but wanted to add multiple workgroups.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Even on Windows you can only set the computer to one workgroup, so setting multiple on Mac isn't going to be possible.

Comment: In Ubuntu I can, going from Ubuntu to OSX

Comment: Support for MS/Windows networking features on Mac is minimal at best. Whereas Ubuntu is made by people who are much more concerned about it working with other systems.

Comment: Ubuntu uses Samba, so if it's capable of what you ask why not just install that and set it up like on your Ubuntu machine ?